# How to handle memory limitation of GPU for high resolution image processing on GPU?

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

I am making a camera app and this app will be provide some filters to users. Currently my code is on NDK and it works Ok, however i want to make it a bit faster. It seems GPU and opengl Es 2.0 is way to go. My only concern with GPU is that their memory limitation. Since modern cameras take 5-10 mp images while GPU memory limitation is far less than that. I was wondering if there is a way to work around that limitation. The only logical option seems to me is dividing the image smaller part, and then processing them on GPU and finally assamble them to final image. My question is, if this approach still would be good for performance and also is there any other option to image processing high resolution images on mobile GPUs.

Edit: I need to clarify that i want to use GPU for image processing so my goal is not to render results to screen. I will render it to another texture and save it to disk.

Comment: It really depends what it is you are trying to do. The advantage that GPUs offer is that they are highly parallel, but not all problems can be made easier by simply throwing more cores at them.

Comment: I wanted to get a general solution to a general problem however currently i am trying to code "laplacian pyramid" which is very costly when it is done on CPU.

Comment: well, if you are doing something like applying a tint to an image, where you want to apply the same operation to all the bits, then of loading to the GPU is an obvious solution. tasks like blurring an image are a bit trickier, as each pixels new value depends on a range of pixels. In your case though, you have to consider there are a lot of differences between hardware, such as how much ram they support, how large a texture, how much data you can send to them. They may not even be able to do OpenCL style processing

Comment: Tiling can be used for blur too - just provide overlapping regions of the source data, and stitch the output in a proper way.

Comment: Do you need to work around the limitation?  Meaning, does the camera *preview* frame really need to be full resolution or can you get away with capturing lower resolution preview frames while still capturing full-resolution final images?

Comment: I won't use GPU to render results to screen. I will use it to render result on another texture. I am blending three full resolution images with using laplacian and gaussian pyramids. Since this is a camera app( hdr app) users expect it to work on full resolution. I want to use GPU because it is much faster for this kind of operations, nvidia clams that GPUs work 10x faster for laplacian pyramid operation. [Here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2009/SIGGRAPH/Advances_in_GPU_based_Image_Processing.pdf) is the link the paper that are talking about this.

Answer (score 2):

Your tiling idea has been used since the Nintendo Entertainment System, which has a Ricoh 2A03 at 1.79 MHz, so it's a good approach. Google uses tiling to manage map displays, and even games like Crysis tend to limit their texture sizes of most of their textures to something like 1024x1024 (1 megapixel). And yep, 10 megapixels requires 30 megs of RAM, so some devices may have problems, especially since if you use a source and a dest texture, that would mean 60 megs of RAM are required.

Just keep in mind that texture sizes tend to use a power of 2 ( 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc). You'll sometimes get better quality at least if you chop it up and tile up the image.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to apply real-time filters into 10 mp images...
because there aren't such displays(or maybe there are but not in popular use amongst us). :)

So you only need to apply filters on pixels that are being displayed(1900x1280?).
Tiling technique you mentioned still will be of use with some scenarios. Deferred rendering is such an example. X-Box 360 employed both techniques(tiling with deferred) on daily basis. Without tiling it wouldn't be possible because of high memory requirements for deferred technique.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that i won't use gpu to rennder images onto screen. I have nothing to do with screen and its resolution at all. Image processing will be done background and the screen will only show a progressbar. So the GPU memory limitation is still there for me.